# Read ConcurrentHashMap (or similar) in chunks

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, java.util.concurrent

I have a program, that has a `ConcurrentHashMap` where different Threads can add/remove items from the map.

I'm interested to know what's the best approach to read the map in chunks of 25 items.
What I want to do is something like this: user clicks on a button and reads 25 items from the map( doesn't matter the order). After that he can click a "Next" button and read another 25 items( that are different from the first 25 ), and so on.

I'm not sure if I can do this with a `ConcurrentHashMap` . I don't want to use a database , and I want to keep this in memory. 
I don't think converting the `Map` into an `ArrayList` will help, because items are added/ removed from the map, most of the time.

I'm open to any solution, even a 3rd party library.

**UPDATE**: I'm also not tied to `ConcurrentHashMap` . I'm just looking for the best solution

**UPDATE 2**: They keys are `String`

Thanks

Comment: I'd worry about doing this with a `ConcurrentHashMap` because a) it has no fixed ordering, b) it can reflect, or not, changes made to the map after iteration started, in an undefined way.  This seems likely to end badly; honestly, having a user interact with a collection of items getting concurrently modified by other threads seems likely to end badly period.

Comment: @LouisWasserman true, when I started working on the project this feature was not needed, and ConcurrentHashMap was a best solution. That's why I said I'm open to any solution.

Comment: Which operations are performed on the map, can you list all of them? What is "item" - a key, a value or an entry? Edit: can item be re-added to the map? If it can, must it be shown two times/only first, or it makes no difference?

Comment: @user3707125 the operations are add/ remove entries based on key. Item=entry(my bad) . Yes an entry with a certain key can be added, removed than re-added later. The entries have to be shown only one time, but that's not the problem, I can manage to do the removal part from front end, once the entry is deleted on backend, so I can avoid duplicates

Comment: When you are talking about "button clicks", it sounds like it would at least be worth considering to *lock* the data for this time. Reading 25 elements will take a few microseconds, and when it is caused by user interaction it will not happen at high frequency. So this should not noticably/negatively affect the concurrency that you wanted to allow otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, since String keys are strictly ordered, [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) is a way to go.

- It is both [concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) and [navigable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), and can be often used in place of ConcurrentHashMap.
- `get` / `put` / `remove` are as fast as `O(log N)`.
- As a bonus you'll get the natural traversal order for free.

To get the next page from ConcurrentSkipListMap, call `tailMap` with the last key of the previous page as an anchor and then construct an iterator or a stream from the result submap:

```
    return map.tailMap(lastKey, false).entrySet()
            .stream()
            .limit(pageSize)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that `tailMap` will succeed even if the anchor key is removed from the map. The iteration will proceed from the next key larger than the anchor.

---

If keys are not strictly ordered, or if O(1) complexity is required, then you may prefer an alternative suggestion - an open-addressed hash table traversed in the order of cell indices. However there is no such implementation among standard Java classes. The thread-safety of such maps is typically achieved by locking.

Comment: How would this work? Assume one thread adds 2 keys with random string values every second, and one thread removes 1 random key every second, and every 30 seconds we pull 25 out, *which should be not seen before*. If you're ordering on the string, it's possible (probable even) that not more then 25 keys are added in front of the last key. Iterating from the last key then fails?

Comment: @KoosGadellaa This mechanism provides the same guarantees as an `Iterator` of concurrent collections. The traversal is [weekly consistent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly), i.e. 1) it may proceed concurrently with other operations; 2) it never throws ConcurrentModificationException or similar; 3) it is guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

Comment: I meant to say that 'iterating from the last key then produces less then 25 new results, even though there are more then 25 unseen results' 
The iterator is created after the tailset, and a skiplist still orders by key, not by insertion order (which is what would be necessary).

Simply said: my last key in the map is 'Zulu' and my lastSeenKey is 'Zulu' too, and then another thread add 'Amsterdam', 'Brussels', 'Copenhagen' as new keys (with appropriate values). Wouldn't map.tailMap('Zulu', false) ensure that I never see these new unseen values?

Comment: @KoosGadellaa Such iterator will either return a full page of unseen elements or will reach the end, which means all elements present on the first construction of the iterator have been visited. Typically it's an expected behavior from UX perspective. Users expects some consistent order while browsing the pages, they usually don't want to fall into infinite loop of the items that are repeatedly added and removed back and forth.

Comment: So it will eventually 'terminate' since it cannot show any elements since it's index is so far down the items that nothing new is added...   
Even though there may be a gazillion items added which are new.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a concurrenthashmap, you could consider using a linkedhashmap instead, and synchronize it.
A linkedhashmap stores in insertion order, so you can iterate over it.
However, you'll need to keep a lastViewedElement, and, when that is removed, update it with a new, valid, value so you can iterate from there.

It should be synchronized properly (possibly manually) since it's not threadsafe. A rough implementation would be:
(i'm doing this by head, not by IDE, so it might miss things. And my generics are not up to snuff, and you'll probably don't need generics anyway...)

```
public class MyMagicMap<X,Y> implements Map
    private LinkedHashMap<X,Y> innerMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    X lastKey = null;

    @Override
    public void put(X key,Y value) {
        synchronized(MyMagicMap.class) {
            if(innerMap.contains(key)) {
                innerMap.remove(key);
            }
            innerMap.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Y remove(X key) {
        synchronized(MyMagicMap.class) {
            if(key.equals(lastKey) {
                lastKey = getKeyBefore(lastKey);
            }
            return innerMap.remove(key);
        }
    }

    private X getKeyBefore(X oldLastKey) {
        Iterator<X> it = innerMap.KeySet.iterator();
        for(X key : it  ) {
            if(key.equals(oldLastKey)) {
                return it.next();
            }
        }
    }

    public Map<X,Y> getNextBatch(int count) {
         synchronized(MyMagicMap.class) {

             Map<X,Y> resultMap = new HashMap();
             Iterator<X> it = innerMap.keySet().iterator();
             X lastKey = scanForLastKey(it);
             if(lastKey == null) {
                 return resultMap;
             }
             resultMap.put(lastKey, innerMap.get(key);
             for(int i; i < count-1; i++) {
                 if(it.hasNext()) {
                     X key = it.next();
                     resultMap.put(X, innerMap.get(key));
                 }
             }
        }
    }

    private X scanForLastKey(Iterator<X> iterator) {
        if(lastKey == null) {
            iterator.next();
        }
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            X key = iterator.next();
            if(key.equals(lastKey)) {
                return key;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }




    // other map methods can probably go without synchronization
}
```

To note is that there is thread synchronization on the relevant blocks, only one thread should do this.
Also note that the delete method is performing badly (O(N))
If you want to do it quicker, you'll have to implement your own LinkedHashMap with which allows you to efficiently determine the next in line. Sounds hard, until you realize you just need a HashMap> with the triplet having keyvalues of previous and next. Synchronize the put and remove operation again, which are made to keep the integrity of the list, i.e.

```
void put(X key, Y value) {
    // synchronize this
    Triplet<X,Y,X> lastValueInMap = innerMap.get(endOfMapKey);
    lastValueInMap.rightElement = key;
    innerMap.put(X, new Triplet(endOfMapKey, value, null);
    endOfMapKey = key;
}
Y remove(X key) {
    // synchronize this.
    Triplet<X,Y,X> valueTriplet = innerMap.remove(key);
    if(valueTriplet.left != null)
        if(valueTriplet.right != null) {
            innerMap.get(valueTriplet.left).right = valueTriplet.right;
            innerMap.get(valueTriplet.right).left=valueTriplet.left;
        } else
        // etc.
     }
}
```

Last thing to note is the put method, which explicitly removes keys if they're already there instead of updating the value. Since LinkedHashMap's updates do not modify insertion order, it would mean that if the removal is not done, any key K which is already read in a batch and later updated would never be shown in a newer batch.

Comment: From what I know linkedhashmap is not thread safe. Am I wrong?